# How can I launch pipes and redirects commands with Process.Start?

Tags: c#

I'm using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() to remotely launch commands on a Linux os. Until now I have been able to launch simple commands and then read the output.
For example I can execute the command `echo Hello World` and read `Hello World` as its output.

Here's the simplified code:

```
public void Execute(string file, string args) {
    Process process = new Process {
        StartInfo = {
            FileName = file,
            Arguments = args,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false
        }
    };
    process.Start();
}
```

To be clearer, I use the code above like this: `Execute("echo", "Hello World");`.

Here's my problem: as long as I execute simple commands everything works smooth, but I'd like to launch commands with pipes and redirects, in order to have a stronger control on the command and on its output (without handle the output itself as text).
So, is there a workaround (or maybe a specific library) to achieve this result?

Comment: I think you have simplified your code just a smidgen too much.  There's nothing here indicating how the command is executed on a remote host.

Comment: Well Pipes are essentially data streams and if you want to have control over the I/O of your target process you won't be able to dodge **streams**, especially, if you are working cross-platform, as Windows implements streams/pipes differently than Linux and .NET provides an abstract layer by giving you the `Stream` class.

Comment: You'll need to get the standard pipes from the process for example `Process.StandardOutput` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So, in case I want to use pipes, I basically have to read the `Process.StandardOutput` and **then** handle what I read, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to execute commands in Linux with all the shell features (including pipelines, redirections etc.) use the following code:

```cs
public static Process ExecuteInBash(string command)
{
    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = 
        {
            FileName = "bash",
            ArgumentList = { "-c", "--", command },
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false
        }
    };
    process.Start();
    return process;
}
```

Mind that this method is non-blocking, it starts the process and does not wait for it to finish. In order to block you have to call the `process.WaitForExit()` method. Also, it is a good idea to check the [exit code](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Exit-Status) to find out whether the command succeeded or failed. Example:

```cs
var process = ExecuteInBash("echo Hello");
process.WaitForExit();
var standardOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
var standardError = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
if (process.ExitCode == 0)
{
    // Command succeeded.
}
```

Comment: This just does the job as expected. I had tried using sudo as filename, that was failing to do with pipes. bash is excecuting pipe redirection without any issue. Thanks @Dzienny .

Comment: @HarishPatil Good that you brought my attention to this old answer, because I noticed an issue with it. In the old code you could not use double quotes within the `command` without extra escaping. It is fixed now. And I added some remarks.