# Piping output into to a windows executable started by [Diagnostics.Process]::Start?

Tags: windows, powershell

How does one send an `echo y` pipe to `plink` when starting them from `[Diagnostics.Process]::Start`

```
$meProcessID = ([Diagnostics.Process]::Start("echo y | plink.exe", "$($hostName) -l $($uPwd.GetNetworkCredential().Username) -pw $($uPwd.GetNetworkCredential().Password) \`"echo '$($uPwd.GetNetworkCredential().Password)' | sudo -S '/home/someuser/somescript.sh'\`"")).Id
```

Though there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156498/how-can-i-launch-pipes-and-redirects-commands-with-process-start) it doesn't really answer my question since it's asking about calling bash from powershell and mine is really about passing a value to a Window command from standard output to bypass a `Host-Read` type of prompt.

Comment: `echo` and pipes on Windows are shell-builtin features (in both CMD and PowerShell). They're not available outside a shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ansgar Wiechers' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53695459/45375) contains an effective solution and sensible security warnings.

Using a `System.Diagnostics.Process` *instance* with `.RedirectStandardInput = $true`, and use of `.StandardInput` to provide standard input after the process has started, gives you more flexibility, yet in your case **the only modification that was needed was to pass your command line as an *argument* (2nd parameter), via option `-c`, to *program* `cmd.exe` (1st parameter)**.

- `[Diagnostics.Process]::Start()`'s *first* parameter is only the *executable name / path*, not a full command line.
- It is the *2nd parameter* that accepts a string containing the *arguments* to pass to the executable.
- Since you're using *shell* features, namely connecting *multiple* commands with a *pipeline*, you must use `cmd.exe` as the executable, and pass your pipeline as an *argument* to `cmd.exe`'s `/c` option.

  - You could use `powershell.exe` too, but in this simple case it is sufficient - and faster - to use `cmd.exe`.

Here's a simplified example:

```
$meProcessID = ([Diagnostics.Process]::Start(
  # Program to launch
  'cmd',
  # Arguments to pass
  '/c echo 42 | powershell -nop -c "''stdin input: '' + $Input" & pause'
).Id
```

The above demonstrates that stdin input `42` is seen by the `powershell` process as such (`$Input`); it opens a new console window that shows the following:

```
stdin input: 42
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: @leeand00: Ah, yes, hadn't considered that you wanted just the PID - thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect STDIN of the receiving process. Something like this:

```
$username = $uPwd.GetNetworkCredential().Username
$password = $uPwd.GetNetworkCredential().Password

$p = New-Object Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo.FileName = 'plink.exe'
$p.StartInfo.Arguments = $hostName, '-l', $username, '-pw', $password,
    "`"echo '${password}' | sudo -S '/home/someuser/somescript.sh'\`""
$p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = $true
$p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$p.Start()

$p.StandardInput.WriteLine('y')

$p.Id  # get the PID
```

With that said, I assume that the `echo y` is for accepting the host key. Doing that effectively disables an important SSH security mechanism to counter Man-in-the-Middle attacks, so I *strongly* recommend against doing this. It's better to verify the SSH host key of the remote host and import it into the registry before doing automated connections. You could prepare a .reg file with the hash and import that wherever needed. You may also want to use public key authentication instead of password authentication.

You have been warned.